# Handler and messages

Tags: android, handler, message

I try to send message from  class that handles background process for my application communicates with server and prace responce than serialize the objects and send it to activity that visualise results. Activity has a public handler.

```
public final Handler _handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String smsg = msg.getData().toString();
        if (!smsg.contains("endResult")) {
            Log.d("New 10 a","New 10");
            deviceBasicList a = (deviceBasicList) msg.getData()
                    .getSerializable("devices");
            List<deviceBasic> basicList = a.getList();
            setDeviceList(basicList);
        } else {
            hideLoadingDialog();
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }

};
```

In the background process class I have an instance of the activity

```
this.searchActivity = a;
```

After I parce the objects im sending message :

```
private void sendDeviceList() {
    if (!this.deviceList.isEmpty()) {
        deviceBasicList basicList = new deviceBasicList(this.deviceList);
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.setTarget(this.searchActivity._handler);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("devices", basicList);
        msg.setData(bundle);
        this.searchActivity._handler.sendMessage(msg);
        this.deviceList.clear();
    }
}
```

Because of the large amounts of data Im sending information for objects 10 by 10. 
The result is that In the background class I send exact amount of messages I should, but in the activity im reciveing about 5 times more that I have send.

Comment: its impossible, you cannot get more Messages then sent

Comment: Log.d("New 10 a","New 10"); 


This is how I figured out Im reciving more than I send.

Comment: add Log.d when handler.sendMessage(msg);

Comment: You were right there was a algorithm error in the backend class. Messages are working correctly.